# Nodemailer default options issue

Tags: node.js, default, nodemailer

Using Nodemailer v.6.9.4 on Node.js v18.16.0.

Doing a basic send against our hardware appliance works in both cases, but when the "from:" is a default option I get nothing in FROM: (FROM: <>)... our appliance delivers it internally anyway, but it looks funny.  Tested against a gmail address and it is never delivered (which would be expected missing a FROM:).  When I move it to mailOptions in sendMail, it works as expected and I get a proper FROM: in the email (delivered both internally and to my gmail address).  I'm not entirely sure I've set my defaults in the transporter correctly, but I've tried a couple different ways with the same results.  The docs give no example on using defaults (that I've found) but suggest this very use case, so I must be doing something wrong.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    logger: true,
    debug: true,
    host: "my.hardware.appliance",
    port: 25,
    defaults: {
        from: '"SysAdmin" <sysadmin@mydomain.com',
    },
})

async function monthlyStorageMetrics() {
    const doMail = await transporter.sendMail({
        //from: '"SysAdmin" <sysadmin@mydomain.com>',
        to: "ManagerJoe@mydomain.com",
        subject: "Monthly Metrics",
        text: "Your report",
    })
}

module.exports = {
    monthlyStorageMetrics,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Follow my steps to fix your question

1. Your usage is wrong, missing a matched `>` symbol.

> change your code from `<sysadmin@mydomain.com` to `<sysadmin@mydomain.com>`

2. Make sure that you have the right config for your `host` and `port`

- host: `pop` or `imap`
- port: `25` or `994`, or other port

3. Please follow the official API usage of `defaults` options, if you are not sure how to config.

```bash
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(options[, defaults])
```

https://nodemailer.com/smtp/

4. If you're still not sure if it's correct, in `VS Code` Ctrl-click to go to the Typescript method type the definition file, and make sure it's correct.

```
export function createTransport(
    transport?: SMTPTransport | SMTPTransport.Options | string,
    defaults?: SMTPTransport.Options,
): Transporter<SMTPTransport.SentMessageInfo>;
// ...
```

### The correct default configuration is shown in the code below.

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  // Check both of the host and port is right ✅
  host: "imap.mydomain.com",
  port: 25,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: "sysadmin@mydomain.com",
    pass: "sysadmin's password",
  },
}, {
  // Here is the default message options object ✅
  from: 'SysAdmin <sysadmin@mydomain.com>',
})

async function monthlyStorageMetrics() {
  const doMail = await transporter.sendMail({
    // from: 'SysAdmin <sysadmin@mydomain.com>',
    to: 'ManagerJoe <managerjoe@mydomain.com>',
    subject: "Monthly Metrics",
    text: "Your report",
  })
}

// test
monthlyStorageMetrics().catch(console.error);

// module.exports = {
//   monthlyStorageMetrics,
// }
```

> screenshot ✅

[image]

### refs

https://nodemailer.com/

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it's fixed now in the example.  However, my working code was exactly as you show, no difference.  When I attempt to put From: in the defaults, I get:

`DEBUG [7yTGAxbLJ8] C: MAIL FROM:<>`

When I move it to mailOptions, I get:

`DEBUG [sD22TgxEags] C: MAIL FROM:<SysAdmin@mydomain.com>`

Comment: Please do not edit your question use the answer content.

Comment: Appreciate the attempt, but like I said in my original question, I want the FROM: to be DEFAULT use in the transport, not part of the MailOptions as you show.  My code works just fine when I put FROM in the mailOptions but the docs clearly state my use case
`defaults – is an object that is going to be merged into every message object. This allows you to specify shared options, for example to set the same from address for every message`.  Our appliance is IP-restricted and requires no auth and yes, it's over 25.

Comment: Where does the API documentation say that `default` is a valid option in `createTransport`? Show me the link.

Comment: Unless I'm reading this wrong it's `https://nodemailer.com/smtp/`

Comment: Awesome, I knew it must be something simple.  Appreciate the tip about VS Code as well, it was trying to lead me correctly but I wasn't paying attention.